# ListView.setFooterView(v) Footer change not visible In ListView displayed by VIewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I call

```
listView.setFooterView(v)
```

but no change is visible.  Now I should add that the listView is inside a view (not a frament) that is added into a ViewPager.

So the View that holds the listView is inside the view pager.  If I switch back and forth between the views then I see the change, but not otherwise.  So far I have tried invalidating most everything including the whole ViewPager but still it does not show.

Inside activities layout I have:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Then I have three pages each looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/listListDisplayer1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listMyList1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

<include layout="@layout/advertisement" />

</FrameLayout>
```

So I have views like above and create them right away in onCreate() of the main activity.

```
 MyPageAdapter extends ViewPagerAdapter{

      int getCount() {
           return 3;
      }

       public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        View view=null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                view = getMyView1();
                break;
            case 1:
                view = getMyView2();
                break;
            case 2:
                view = getMyView2();
                break;
        }

        if ((view != null) && ((ViewPager) collection).findViewById(view.getId()) == null)
        {

          ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        }

        return view;
    }


    private View getMyView1()
    {   
        return mMyView1;
    }


    private View getMyView2()
    {
        return  mMyView2;
    }



    private View getMyView3()
    {
        return mMyView3;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View view, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) view).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View view) {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object arg1) {
        return view == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable parcel, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View view) {


    }


}
```

I will update with a few more lines ....

```
     private class PageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNum) {
        Logout.debug("pageSelected :"+pageNum); 
        if (pageNum == 0)
        {
            prepareMyView1();
        }
        else if (pageNum == 2)
        {
           prepareMyView2();
        }
        else if (pageNum == 3)
        {
            prepareMyView3();
        }
    }

}

    private void prepareMyView1()   // each is like this setting adapter on ListView
{   
    setMyList1Adapter();
}

     private void prepareMyView2()   // each is like this setting adapter on ListView
{   
    setMyList2Adapter();
}
```

So I want a change in addFooterView to be effected | visible immediately.

Comment: are you setting this in your ViewPager adapter's instantiateView()?

Comment: No. I do a setCurrentItem() this sets adapter etc.  The list starts loading.  I get an error message back, and do a setFooterView(), but its not visible.  Until I switch back and forth.

Comment: try my answer, let me know if it works, i'm using viewpager extensively, but i'm too lazy to look up my code on my pc.

Comment: So I would check some boolean to see if there was an error message and if so, add it inside instantiate view?

Comment: not sure i understood what error you're talking about. just try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on your PagerAdapter after you setFooterView(v) wherever you're doing this.

Comment: I've added it everywhere I call addFooterView(v). But still it does not show up.

Comment: I can't post the whole file really.  Its 2000+ lines and proprietary.

Comment: But I will post what I can.  Just a minute.

Comment: Ok. I posted.  The layouts per page are created immediately in the onCreate() of the main Activity.

Comment: Now it does not work on the first view page for example. Never mind the other two.

Comment: Same problem guys.. tried all your stuffs .. No Solutions yet

Answer (score 18):

The solution to this is to first add the footer view and then set the adapter.  if the adapter is set first and then the footer view is added it does now show up. removeFooterView(v) can be used without resetting the adapter however.

Answer (score 0):

Your should call notifyDataSetChanged() on your ViewPager's adapter.

Comment: Still does not show.  Only switching between pages/views makes it show.

Comment: I've posted most of it above.

Comment: It gets called.  But the footer is not visible.