# ListView.addFooterView(v) not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView declared inside a layout.  When I addFooterView(v) it does NOT display.  What are the possible reasons for this?  Is there some setting in ListView or my Adapter to make this display immediately?  It does eventually display but only after reinitializing the view, adapter and all.

Update: It seems that resetting the adapter finally makes it appear ....  Obviously not something that I should have to do everytime I call addFooterView(v).

The view containing the ListView is inside a View maintained by PageViewer so not sure if that effects this or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView.setFooterView(v) Footer change not visible In ListView displayed by VIewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993320/listview-setfooterviewv-footer-change-not-visible-in-listview-displayed-by-vie)

Comment: thanks alextsc. any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I have an idea, but without the code I can't say for sure. Though I think you are just reposting the linked question for more attention. I don't answer reposts in general, so my guess doesn't matter much.

Comment: so that's why you answered the first post when you saw it? or did you find the old post while you where helping with this one ....

Comment: As someone already pointed out in your other question, your first post didn't include any code that made use of footer methods. No code, no help, as said. Also I just said that I won't answer duplicates. That doesn't mean that I answer everything that is not a duplicate of course.

Comment: Fixed from API19

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add the footer view before you set the adapter is the only thing we can replicate with when we are not able to see your code.

Comment: this does work. However I am dynamically setting the footer based on progress and error messages so not sure if resetting the adapter is the way to go ...

Comment: @Code Droid: You should only set the adapter once.

Comment: yes, but I am setting the footer more than once. Perhaps there is some update action in setting the adapter that might give a clue.

Comment: What is the disadvantage anyway of resetting the adapter after setting the footer?  I am generally only setting the footer when the listview is empty.  a loading message or an error message.

Comment: But use `removeFooterView()` to remove your footer. No need to reset the adapter just because you need to hide your footer view.

Comment: Fixed from API19