# button at bottom of list view is now showing up

Tags: android, listview, button

Im trying to add a button which appears at the bottom of a list view as it will be a load more button... The button is not showing.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,R.layout.list_item,
        new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

setListAdapter(adapter);

// selecting single ListView item
ListView lv = getListView();
// Getting listview from xml


// Creating a button - Load More
Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

SOLVED: i needed to do it before adapter was set

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
    lv = getListView();
    // Creating a button - Load More
    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
    lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011909/listview-addfooterviewv-not-displaying ("Add the footer view before you set the adapter..")

Comment: Boris is wright. Boris, put this as an answer to get voted

Comment: Thanks, it works great :) .. put as an answer and il vote up